# Download dependency packages from maven repository failed in Gradle build but download directly successfully

Tags: maven, gradle, repository

When I used Gradle to download dependency packages from manven repository, always got timeout.

> Could not download log4j-core-2.17.1.jar (org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.17.1)
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.17.1/log4j-core-2.17.1.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.17.1/log4j-core-2.17.1.jar'.
> > Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.40.215] failed: Read timed out
> Could not download log4j-api-2.17.1.jar (org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.17.1)
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.17.1/log4j-api-2.17.1.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.17.1/log4j-api-2.17.1.jar'.
> > Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.40.215] failed: Read timed out
> Could not download commons-configuration2-2.2.jar (org.apache.commons:commons-configuration2:2.2)
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-configuration2/2.2/commons-configuration2-2.2.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-configuration2/2.2/commons-configuration2-2.2.jar'.
> > Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.40.215] failed: Read timed out
> Could not download jersey-apache-connector-2.26.jar (org.glassfish.jersey.connectors:jersey-apache-connector:2.26)
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jersey/connectors/jersey-apache-connector/2.26/jersey-apache-connector-2.26.jar'.
> > Could not HEAD 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jersey/connectors/jersey-apache-connector/2.26/jersey-apache-connector-2.26.jar'.
> > Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.40.215] failed: Read timed out

But when I try to download the package by wget, it is successful. So weird. Who can help me on this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: This looks like a network problem: ` failed: Read timed out`..

Comment: @khmarbaise It is possible. Debugging on it.